# JS namespacing and page-load

Tags: javascript, namespaces, closures, onpageloadstring

I've read about how to make a JS namespace, but my question is how can I make sure the functions inside would only happen on page load?
i.e. instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function () {...});
```

(or any other lib then jquery).

also - is there a way to control what will launch on page load and what would before?

Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses an immediate-function to encapsulate the Code and registers an event-handler on the event `DOMContentReady` which fires when the Browser has the DOM ready but bevor Images are loaded.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var
  init = function () {
    window.console.info('init()');
  };

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentReady', init, false);
}());
```

The immediate-function gets executet as soon as the browser loads the code. From that point there are different events on which further code-execution can be scheduled.

Without using a framework like jquery, which puts some effort in this toppic, you have to handle different events in different browser by your own.

Answer (score 0):

put this code out of jquery code

```
 var MyReallyCoolLibrary = {
awesome: "stuff",
doSomething: function() {
},
doAnotherThing: function() {
}
```

};

```
   MyReallyCoolLibrary.awesome;

   alert(MyReallyCoolLibrary.awesome);
```